# How do I add 2 anchor tabs for 2 different recipients?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to add two different anchor tabs, which search for two different strings ("signer", "co-signer") and apply a different recipient to each tab. When I send the envelope using the SOAP API, the first recipient receives the document, signs and completes it but the second recipient never receives it.

When I login to my DocuSign account, the flow looks correct.

I can also reproduce this using the DocuSign client.

Is this a limitation of the anchor tabs?

Comment: Can you post your API request and response with sensitive date removed? As well as the response? Which SOAP API Endpoint are you using?

Comment: Very hard to tell without seeing the actual request you're sending to DocuSign.  As Andrew states please post your request with any sensitive info removed (using the old Console UI you can enable request logging through your preferences, see this [article](https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/question/api-request-logging).  Also, do you see the same behavior using the REST api?

Comment: Sorry for the really late response. The problem wasn't code related. I was trying to send an envelope to an email address belonging to the account admin and it wasn't working. When I tried 2 other email addresses, it was fine.